# What is wrong with my derivation for arc radius?

Tags: geometry

We are trying to find the value of $y$ so that $y$ is the radius of the arc.

[image]

1. The value of $y$ is going to be the number such that the distance from $(0, y)$ to $(0, c)$ is the same as the distance from $(0, y)$ to $(a/2, 0)$.
2. So we need to solve the equation

$\sqrt{(c-y)^2} = \sqrt{(y)^2 + (a/2)^2}$

$(c-y)^2 = (y)^2 + (a/2)^2$

$c^2 - 2yc + y^2 = y^2 + (a/2)^2$

$c^2 - 2yc + y^2 = y^2 + (a/2)^2$

$y = \frac{c^2-(a/2)^2}{2c}$

3. Now the radius must be the distance from $(0, y)$ to $(a/2, 0)$.

$$R = \sqrt{\left(\frac{c^2-(a/2)^2}{2c}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{4}}$$

$$ = \sqrt{\frac{(c^2-(a/2)^2)^2}{4c^2} + \frac{a^2 c^2}{4c^2}}$$

$$ = \sqrt{\frac{c^4 - c^2a^2/2 +(a/2)^4}{4c^2} + \frac{a^2 c^2}{4c^2}}$$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{c^4 + \frac{1}{2}c^2a^2 +(a/2)^4}}{2c}$$

By dimensional analysis, the units are correct...but I'm not sure that this is the right formula. Can anybody offer criticism and suggestions?

Comment: What makes you think the argument is wrong?

Comment: You can also say that $R=y+|c|$

Comment: Your expression for $y$ is fine, but you got a couple of signs wrong in the last formula, when expanding the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding upon the other answers, a straightforward approach is
$$
  (c - y)^2 - y^2 = a^2/4 \implies
  (c - y - y) (c- y + y) = a^2/4 \implies c - 2y = a^2/4c
$$
or
$$
 y = \frac{1}{2}(c - a^2/4c)
$$
which is what you have.

Radius is $R = |c - y|$, i.e.,
$$
 R = \left|c - \frac{1}{2}(c - a^2/4c)\right| = \left|\frac{1}{2}(c + a^2/4c)\right|
$$